# Problems with contravariance in Scala

Tags: scala, typeclass

I want to define a type-class like this:

```
trait CanFold[-T, R] {
  def sum(acc: R, elem: T): R
  def zero: R
}

implicit object CanFoldInts extends CanFold[Int, Int] {
  def sum(x: Int, y: Int) = x + y
  def zero = 0
}

implicit object CanFoldSeqs extends CanFold[Traversable[_], Traversable[_]] {
  def sum(x: Traversable[_], y: Traversable[_]) = x ++ y
  def zero = Traversable()
}

def sum[A, B](list: Traversable[A])(implicit adder: CanFold[A, B]): B = 
  list.foldLeft(adder.zero)((acc,e) => adder.sum(acc, e))
```

However, the problem is when I do this I get a `Traversable[Any]` and it
would be nice to get a `Traversable[Int]` instead:

```
 scala> sum(List(1,2,3) :: List(4, 5) :: Nil)
 res10: Traversable[Any] = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
```

To make matters worse, I cannot define an implicit for
`Traversable[Int]` after defining one for `Traversable[_]`, because then
the definitions would cause ambiguity. After pulling my hair out I
gave up.

Is there any way I could make that sum return a
`Traversable[T]` instead of a `Traversable[Any]`?

Looking at how `sum()` is defined on `Seq` in Scala's library, I can see it works with `Numeric`, which is invariant, but I want default implementations for supertypes and having the result be different than the input (same as the fold operation) is nice.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The only way I know to add type parameters to such type classes is to use a `def` instead of an `object`:

```
implicit def CanFoldSeqs[A] = new CanFold[Traversable[A], Traversable[A]] {
  def sum(x: Traversable[A], y: Traversable[A]) = x ++ y
  def zero = Traversable()
}

scala> sum(List(1, 2, 3) :: List(4, 5) :: Nil)
res0: Traversable[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
```

Comment: Oh wow, and that works! ... however it's a def that returns an instance of the trait you want and I was under the impression that implicit params must be concrete instances ... this is awesome :-)

Comment: @goral: Because `object` can't take type parameters.

Comment: @sschaef is this knowledge pure experience, docs or some other source?

Comment: @goral: It doesn't make sense that an `object` takes type parameters, so it is based on logic/what is written in the spec.

Comment: so is there any advantage of using `implicit object`s over `implicit def`s since latter keeps the type?

Comment: @goral: an `object` doesn't create an instance every time it is called, which is the case for `def`.

Comment: This totally solves a problem I was having! it's like the best stack overflow reply ever :)